# Do IDS/IPS/HIDS slow your network down?

Tags: network

Implying I were to use port mirroring, would it increase my network's jitter/ping and other networking matters?

Comment: This is no longer about IDS, then. This is about the port mirroring.

Comment: How is DNS relevant to an IDS?

Comment: Port mirroring is required for IDS I guess? A DNS forwarder is relevant to the network.

Comment: Port mirroring is not required for IDS. Your title is about IDS. DNS is a completely different issue, concept, and question. Please keep questions to a single theme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Implying I were to use port mirroring, would it increase my network's jitter/ping and other networking matters?

They won't change the network performance if you are using port mirroring. The switch will just copy the packet to two interfaces, and the IPS/IDS will analyse it outside of the traffic. But it's not possible to use port mirroring on HIDS: the **H** means *Host*, and it's host-based.

Things change if the IPS/IDS isn't using port mirroring, and for all HIDS, because it would have to receive every packet, decode them, analyse them, and decide what to do with the package. That takes time, even if just a little. The more complex is the solution, the more latency it will add to the traffic.

> I'm using a local DNS server/forwarder, would it cause any issues?

Depend on what kind of issue: security, speed, freshness or another issue.

Security issues depend on how protected are your DNS server. Speed is usually better when you have a local DNS caching requests. Freshness will depend on how long-lived is the DNS cache, and it's a tradeoff against speed.

Answer (score 1):

> Do IDS/IPS/HIDS slow your network down?

Since you usually pass packets through your IDS/IPS filters, that'll at least increase latency. Most of the times it'll also limit your bandwidth, depending on your network's bandwidth and the filter's performance.

> Implying I were to use port mirroring, would it increase my network's jitter/ping and other networking matters?

If you use port mirroring/monitoring that doesn't increase forwarding latency or bandwidth. Note that this passive method can in no way *prevent* intrusion, so it's IDS only. Also, the monitoring port and the monitoring appliance/host need to be able to cope with the bandwidth of the entire monitored traffic. Any traffic dropped in this way isn't analyzed.

DNS isn't relevant to your question.

Comment: Hmm, this contradicts Thorium's answer (due to port mirroring), but you seem to be a mod so you should know your stuff.

Comment: I don't see the contradiction really. Please don't prefer an answer just because it's from a moderator. I just wanted to offer a slightly different or perhaps more precise point of view (especially the non-IPS part).

Answer (score 0):

> Do IDS/IPS/HIDS slow your network down?

This is too broad to answer in general. But, yes they *could* slow down your network.

On the other hand, many of these functionalities can be implemented in part with hardware, which helps increase their speed. Companies that sell these products understand that no one wants the network to slow down, and they presumably work hard to minimize the effect of their hardware.

Thus it is also *possible* to introduce these types of appliances with little perceivable slowdown (maybe no perceivable slowdown).

If it is all implemented in software, it could perhaps more likely cause some slowdown, but it's hard to say how noticeable it would be without knowing more about your specific network and how you use it.